# Using same repository and entities for different transaction manager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement where, I have to create two transaction manager one is pointing to replica DB and another is pointing to master DB, however, the Entities and Repository will same.
While updating a record using Master Transaction manager I am getting below exception.
I am calling the update to the repository from a public Method which has @Transactional annotation defining the master transaction manager and Propagation as Required.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

Can anyone please help here

Comment: Are you using spring data jpa? Share you code here

Comment: Yes.I am using spring data jpa

Comment: Can you please post transaction manager config and that "public method"?

Comment: And the full stack trace, please.

Comment: Thank you all for your time. Issue has been resolved , so here I used Exchange PlatformRoutingDataSource with single TransaactionManager .